# Return only one record (most recent) from a large data set

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to pull the most recent removed date as one line item.
The below query lists all the names. However, in the output I just want one line item that shows the name with most recent removed date. How do I go about doing this?

```
select table1.name, table1.removed_date
from table1
where table1.status = 'Removed' and table1.removed_date is not null
order by table1.removed_date desc
```

Comment: What is the time precision of the `removed_date` column? day? millisecond? Is there a timestamp column such as "last updated time"? More information about your table and data would aid an accurate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `limit 1` at the end of your query. Yes, that is the answer.

Comment: by far the simplest too.

Answer (score 0):

This may go a bit extreme, but after careful consideration, I suppose there is still a chance that two timestamps could collide even with a precision of milliseconds. Therefore, to define the most recent record, we can take advantage of the latest legit transaction by MySQL. Thus a table recording the latest UPDATE could be very helpful. Fundamentally, the table only needs one line and one column which records the ID of table1(supposing the OP's table1 does have one to avoid duplicate names).  Then an UPDATE trigger can do the rest of the job. Here is the code I wrote and tested on workbench:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TABLE latest_removal (id int(11) )//
insert latest_removal values(null)//
create trigger latest_removed  before  update on table1 for each row begin
if old.status != new.status and new.status='removed' then
update latest_removal set id=old.id ;
set new.removed_date=current_date(); -- This is optional as people may prefer manual updating.
end if;
end //
```

Please leave a comment if you find this helpful. Thank you.